# Projection from Mongo API C# driver not supported while querying DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using following code (MongoDB C# driver) to projects fields ,
where `queryDocument = '{{ "FullName" : /myname/i }}'`

```
BsonDocument projectionDefination = Builders.Projection.ToBsonDocument();
projectionDefination.Add(new BsonElement("FullName", "myname"));
collection.Find(queryDocument).Project(projectionDefination);
```

getting following error:

```
{"Command failed."}

{{ "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 9, "errmsg" : "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '9'.", "$err" : "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '9'." }}
```

Can anyone update on this?

I also tried above with RoboMongo

```
Command: db.getCollection('Employee').find({ "FullName": /User/i}).projection({ "FullName" : "$FullName" })
```

Received following error:

```
Error: error: {
"_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 9,
"errmsg" : "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '15'.",
"$err" : "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '15'."
}
```

Comment: It worked with following command

Command: db.getCollection('Employee').find({ "FullName": /User/i}).projection({ "FullName" : 1 })

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this issue and I could encounter the same issue:

[image]

As mongoDB document states about **Projection** in [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

> The projection parameter determines which fields are returned in the matching documents. The projection parameter takes a document of the following form:
>
> `{ field1: <value>, field2: <value> ... }`
>
> The `<value>` can be any of the following:
>
> - 1 or true to include the field in the return documents.
> - 0 or false to exclude the field.